# Android - Scandit - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Scandit SDK started crashing when initializing.  It was working fine, but it just started erroring out.  I have tried googling around for a solution, and I've tried every suggestion. But nothing seems to fix it. It doesn't seem to be a proguard issue and the build path seems correct.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25471): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load scanditsdk-android-3.5.3 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.example-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.initializeRecognitionEngine(ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.java:1364)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.<init>(ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.java:333)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.mirasense.scanditsdk.ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.<init>(ScanditSDKBarcodePicker.java:255)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.venueplus.android.VPScannerActivity.onCreate(VPScannerActivity.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(25471):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with a Scandit engineer, it turns the problem was that I didn't have a directory named "armeabi-v7a" in addition to "armeabi".  So the libscandit-sdk-android-3.5.3.so file must be present in both subfolders.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: TY, you save me dozen hours.